# Complex analysis cycle

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading "Complex Variables" written by R. B. Ash & W. P. Novinger, and in the 3rd chapter I've got stuck. I have questions concerning the following definition.

Let $\gamma_1, \gamma_2, \ldots, \gamma_n$ be a closed curves. If $k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_n$ are integers, then the formal sum $\gamma = \sum_{l=1}^n k_l\gamma_l$ is called a cycle. We define $\gamma^* = \bigcup_{j=1}^n \gamma_j^*$, and for any continious function $f$ on $\gamma^*$

$$
\int_{\gamma}f(\omega)d\omega = \sum_{j=1}^nk_j\cdot \int_{\gamma_j}f(\omega)d\omega.
$$

Finally for $z\not\in \gamma^*$, define

$$
n(\gamma, z) = \sum_{j=1}^{n}k_j\cdot n(\gamma_j, z).
$$

My questions are:

1. Suppose, that for each $j$ $\gamma_j\colon [a_j, b_j]\to \mathbb{C}$. What do we know about each interval $I_j = [a_j, b_j]$? For example if $I_j\cap I_l = \emptyset$ if $j\neq l$?
2. I think about $\gamma$ like this. $\gamma\colon [0,1]\to \mathbb{C}$ is a path, and for each $j$

$$
\gamma(t) = \gamma_j( (j-nt)a_j + (nt - (j-1))b_j) \quad \hbox{if} \quad\frac{j-1}{n} \le t \le \frac{j}{n}.
$$
Is that correct?

3. If 2. is correct than I don`t understand the motivation of the definition of $n(\gamma, z)$.

Please, help me get some intuition :)

Comment: 2. can't be right, because you have a problem of multiple values at $j/n.$

Comment: You're not really supposed to think of $\gamma$ as a path, but rather a *formal* combination of paths. Of course, your definition is perfectly correct: you can break $[0,1]$ up into $n$ intervals and define a path that is $\gamma_i$ on the $i^{th}$ interval. But this makes the formal linear combination idea confusing, since it's not necessarily true that the path you get by doing first $\gamma_1$ and then $\gamma_2$ is the same as the path you get by reversing the order. A cycle is supposed to just be an element in the free abelian group with "basis" given by the actual paths.

Comment: It would appear that these definitions are going to set up some version of the residue theorem or Cauchy's integral formula. The idea is that since both $n(\gamma, z)$ and $\int_\gamma f$ are defined by linearity from their definitions on the $\gamma_i$, statements relating the two concepts on the $\gamma_i$ generalize easily to the case of a cycle. This generalization doesn't seem very useful or important at first, but the idea of turning paths into a group (called the first homology group) is very powerful  and allows you to give more sophisticated theorems later.

Comment: Thanks a lot, cycle is just a formal sum, witch tells me how many times I walk each path, for example the cycle $\gamma_1 + 3\cdot\gamma_2 - \gamma_3$ tells me to walk $\gamma_1$ one time, than $\gamma_2$ 3 times, and finally walk $\gamma_3$ in the opposite direction, is that right?